# Как в Python 3 применить параметр ко всем встроенным функциям?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пример.

В функции "print" разделитель по-умолчанию " ", а я хочу чтобы он был ",".

Если мне нужно 5 раз выполнить функцию "print", то мне в каждой функции нужно прописывать параметр "sep"

Т. е. получится:

```
print(x1, y1, sep=",")
print(x2, y2, sep=",")
print(x3, y3, sep=",")
print(x4, y4, sep=",")
print(x5, y5, sep=",")
```

Можно ли упростить эту запись как-то так?

```
для всех функций "print" задать параметр "sep=",""
print(x1, y1)
print(x2, y2)
print(x3, y3)
print(x4, y4)
print(x5, y5)
```

Comment: Напишите функцию-обёртку)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сделайте свою функцию:

```
def sprint(*args, sep=",", **kwargs):
    print(*args, sep=sep, **kwargs)
```

Если дополнительные параметры функции print не нужны, то можно сократить до:

```
sprint = lambda *args: print(*args, sep=",")
```

Либо измените поведение функции print:

```
_print = print
print = lambda *args, sep=",", **kwargs: _print(*args, sep=sep, **kwargs)
print(1, 2, 3)
```

Но если кто-то будет использовать ваш код, за такое вам спасибо не скажет!

Comment: Можно лучше. Сделайте дефолтный sep.

Comment: Да, вы правы, можно дефолтным сделать.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич @ Avernial А как сделать дефолтным?

Comment: В обновленном ответе уже по дефолту задано sep=",", т.е. при желании можете поменять.

Comment: @Avernial а более короткой записи нет?

Comment: @Борис нет. Если только не выведете это в отдельный модуль и не сделаете import.

Comment: Можно убрать **kwargs, если уверены что не понадабятся другие параметры функции print.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас действительно такие переменные (`x1` - `x5`, `y1` - `y5`), можно заменить на списки, тогда вывод будет всего двумя строками, и не нужно будет 5 раз указывать разделитель:

```
for xi, yi in zip(x, y):
    print(xi, yi, sep=',')
```